# Gnome shell cursor theme not animating properly

Tags: gnome, themes, cursor

I'm having a problem with my gnome shell cursor theme. After updating to version 23.04 the cursor stopped animating, even though it was working fine before. I've tried reinstalling the theme and even tried other animated themes, but they didn't work either.

For some reason, when I record the screen using gnome shell's recorder and select the "show cursor" option, the animation starts working again as long as I'm recording and the cursor stays in the recording area.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm not sure what's causing this issue or how to fix it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. thank you in advance.